# Cannot read Buffer data from http response in Node.js

Tags: node.js, httprequest, httpresponse

I have a node proxy server in which I am passing through a response from another server. It is returning xml. The resultant XML makes it to the browser but when trying to intercept the response in the proxyResponse.on event, I cant seem to parse out the data. Trying to use chunk.toString() results in unreadable text.

```
            // Handle proxy response data
            proxyResponse.on (
                'data',
                function ( chunk ){

                    if ( debugging ){
                        console.log ( '  < chunk = %d bytes', chunk.length );
                    }
                    xml += chunk.toString();
                    response.write ( chunk, 'utf8');    

                    console.log('Response: '+ xml);
                }
            );
```

Comment: Why are you trying to convert it to a string? Does doing `response.write(chunk)` work?

Comment: I need to capture a parameter from the XML that is received in order to change the flow of control before the request is sent to the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The http headers was the clue that lead to my solution. The chunk was being compressed by Gzip, so I used the Zlib library to unzip the chunk in order to get at the xml inside.

```
var zlib = require('zlib');
// Handle proxy response data
proxyResponse.on (
   'data',
   function ( chunk ){

       if ( debugging ){
           console.log ( '  < chunk = %d bytes', chunk.length );
   }
   xml += chunk;
   response.write ( chunk );    
   zlib.unzip(chunk, function(err, chunk){
   if (!err){
       console.log('Response'+chunk.toString())
   }
   });
});
```